# Best way to save changes in MVVM/Knockoutjs Web App?

Tags: ajax, mvvm, save, knockout.js

I've been playing with KnockoutJS and absolutely love how much it simplifies the design from every angle by keeping stuff from falling through the cracks.  My question is what is the recommended "best practice" for saving the data back to the server?  My understanding is that in a connected MVVM, the first "M" is the data layer and so the dependency tracking and notifications in the ViewModel trigger saves directly back to the data layer.  In a JavaScript app, we are disconnected and selectively save back to the server using AJAX.

The app I'm currently using it in is MVC3 and I absolutely get how to write a "Save" action on my controller, plop a "Save" button somewhere on my page, post the whole ViewModel to that Save action and then persist that to the database.  But what about when you make a quick edit and then save it again?  Or what if a save button doesn't fit the flow of the design? Instead, you want to post to the action every time a change is made on the form with no save button at all?  The ideas that I've bounced around are:

- Post the whole ViewModel every time any change is made and make the Action figure out what is new and what isn't (not ideal, especially for large models, if nothing else because the data transmitted on each save would be unnecessarily large).
- Add a property to each item in the ViewModel that tracks whether it is new and/or changed since the last save.  Then, grep out those items and post only those to the server (I haven't tested this, but I assume this can be done using the _destroy property, as intended for a Rails app).
- Separate into as many smaller ViewModels as is plausible so that any pain from the first two options is minimized (this should probably be done regardless).
- Some other better way?

I'm hopeful there are some good ideas out there that I haven't thought of.  To be able to declaratively bind everything AND still save *efficiently* would be awesome.

Comment: You are conflating MVC (as in ASP.NET MVC) and MVVM.  They are both essentially the same pattern, but MVVM has changes specific for designing against WPF applications.

Comment: Actually KnockoutJS (http://knockoutjs.com) uses the MVVM pattern, which is what the poster was referring too.

Comment: Awesome question! The same question without Knockout would perhaps be even more useful, as that's just one of many, many JS frameworks out there. I'll continue my hunt for _the_ answer to this question.

Comment: -1 Accepted answer link for solution broken. Code should be added to the answer as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other thing i could think of is [subscribing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables).  When i first started reading your post i was thinking flags w/grep though.

Edit: Better yet, `ko.utils.compareArrays` looks promising.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/sr5WK/5/) a working example..

The only thing left to do is detect changes to values of the 'retained' values.  You're well on your way though.

Comment: Wow. +1 for the elegant implementation and I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer for now.  The question was more theoretical in nature, so I'm sure there are still other methods, but the way that example is set up is genius.  Even though there is still a save button in that implementation, the cool part is there doesn't have to be.  As long as something triggers ko.utils.compareArrays, you _could_ selectively post only the arrays you care about.  Which is exactly what I was curious about.  Well done.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: The example link is broken... any chance the example is still available? I have a viewmodel that has several levels of relationships and I've looking for different options on saving

Comment: not sure where it went but it's gone.  if you have a specific question id be willing to take a crack at it.

Comment: Your fiddle was removed because it contained an iframe redirecting to what looks like malware. You might double check your account on jsfiddle to see that it wasn't compromised.

Also, it'd be nice if you included the actual code to your answer rather than just linking to an external resource.

Comment: -1 Accepted answer link for solution broken. Code should be added to the answer as needed.

Answer (score 5):

I just got back from Mix11 where I attended [this session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08) about Knockout.js. It might be worth your while to watch Steve Sanderson crank out a full CRUD demo.

Comment: Yeah, I actually watched that masterful demo last week as soon as it was posted on line.  A truly great demo that shows off what Knockout can do on the client side, but when he posted to the server, it didn't do anything except relay it back to the client to show that it was actually going to the server.  I'm more interested in what the best practice is when saving incremental changes to the server... while keeping the payload small and the controller efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the Mapping plugin for Knockout, it lets you have load up Knockout from a JSON array. If it wasn't too big, you save that array down to server on a timer (or after a change). Hope this helps, sorry if you already knew this.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html